# Set Layout render to false when refreshing a specific html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As title says I want to refresh a specific html element without render the layout, How can I improve this code piece?

```
    function datatablepartialview() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Pracas")',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            render :layout => false,//(this is not working)
            success: function (result) {
                $('#myBody').html(result);
            }
        });
    }        
    function refresh() {
        function RefreshPartial() {
            //this will wait 3 seconds and then fire the load partial function
            setTimeout(function () {
                datatablepartialview();
                //recall this function so that it will continue to loop
                RefreshPartial();
            }, 5000);
        }
        RefreshPartial();
        //initialize the loop           
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to refresh my layout.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. Jquery got some very nice functions to do the work for you. So `.ajax()` is not needed in your case.

Using `.post()` and `.load()` will do the trick
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ <-- post
http://api.jquery.com/load/ <-- load

Oke first lets send that post.

```
  function datatablepartialview() {
        $.post( '@Url.Action("Index", "Pracas")', { post_data:post_data, post_data2:post_data2 })
          .done(function( data ) {
          //now you have send the post you can refresh your `div` here           
          //with .load you can specify the element you want to refresh
             $('#yourElementToLoad).load('yourwebsite.com #yourElementToRefresh');

          });
    };
```

In this case the code will load the data from `#yourElementToLoad` and put it in the `#yourElementToRefresh`.

Comment: About the `{post_data:post_data}`, how do I pass my @model DataTable through that? What about the `'yourwebsite.com'`, what are you refering to? Controller/Action or @Url.Action? Won't your solution just do the same as mine and reload the layout view? I tried a lot of diferent stuffs but it either returns a blank page or nothing happens

Comment: You have to fill in your own data becuase you didn't provide any. 'yourwebsite.com' will be your websites url. or if you work on localhost it wil be localhost. Have you read the manual of .load()? its not just refreshing a view. It goes much deeper.

Comment: server side there's a `return View(dataTable)` to a `@Model DataTable` model on my view which needs to be updated. I already understood that I've to pass the data, Correct me if i'm wrong but I don't see anything related to that on the `.load()` website you gave me. but I'm assuming it would be something like `{ data: dataTable }` or `{ data: model.DataTable }`. I've no idea what's the data syntax relating to the model.

Comment: Look my function is fine, problem is one element of the partial view is also updating... I still don't know why -.-''

Comment: Figured out the problem, was refreshing body instead of the table, the data was being passed correctly But part of the layout was being rendered. I will consider your answer correct, sorry for my bad explanation of the problem.

Comment: Im glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
function datatablepartialview() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Pracas")',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#myTable').load('/Pracas/Index #myTable');
            }
        });
    }
```